# arithmetic operators in linq

Tags: linq, linq-to-sql

do arithmetic operators not allowed in Linq. it giving error + can not applied to lambda expression. CostperResponse.Cost is of datatype decimal

```
        var costperrespone= from v in lstSale
                                 group v by v.ActionGroupName into g
                                 select new CostperResponse
                                 {
                                     ActionGroupName = g.Key,
                                     Cost = ((x => Convert.ToDecimal(x.ResponseROCount))) / ((x => Convert.ToDecimal(x.ResponseWPAmount)) + (x => Convert.ToDecimal(x.ResponseWPAmount)))
                                 };
```

the sqlserver query is

```
     select SUM((cast(isnull(response_ro_count,0) as decimal))/(cast(isnull(response_cp_amount,0)as decimal) + cast(isnull(response_wp_amount,0)as decimal))) , action_group_name from GM_Tempdata where cast(response_ro_count as decimal)>0 group by action_group_name
```

Comment: You're trying to add two lambda expressions together which is probably not what you're after?

Comment: Where did that `x` come from?

Comment: you have to introduce variable with 'let' operator

Comment: What are you trying to accomplish
?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
Cost = ((x => Convert.ToDecimal(x.ResponseROCount))) / ((x => Convert.ToDecimal(x.ResponseWPAmount)) + (x => Convert.ToDecimal(x.ResponseWPAmount)))
```

"means"

```
Cost = (somefunc(x) {Convert.ToDecimal(x.ResponseROCount)))} 
/ (anotherFunc(x) { Convert.ToDecimal(x.ResponseWPAmount))} 
+ lastFunc(x) {Convert.ToDecimal(x.ResponseWPAmount)}))
```

I'm not quite sure what you want to assign to Cost?

Possibly you meant something like

```
Cost = Convert.ToDecimal(v.ResponseROCount) / Convert.ToDecimal(v.ResponseWPAmount) + Convert.ToDecimal(v.ResponseWPAmount)
```

But since you've grouped, you are going to need to use an aggregate like Sum() etc?

Comment: the clear sqlserver query is.      select 
 SUM((cast(isnull(response_ro_count,0) as decimal))/(cast(isnull(response_cp_amount,0)as decimal) + cast(isnull(response_wp_amount,0)as decimal))) ,
 action_group_name 
from 
 GM_Tempdata
where 
 cast(response_ro_count as decimal)>0
group by 
 action_group_name